# Ecto JOIN complications for append-only table query

Tags: append, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm trying to query an Ecto table with append-only semantics, so I'd like *the most recent* version of a complete row for a given ID. The technique is [described here](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/ordering-within-a-sql-group-by-clause#oldest-or-most-recent-records-relative-to-another-field), but in short: I want to JOIN a table on itself with a subquery that fetches the most recent time for an ID. In SQL this would look like:

```sql
SELECT r.*
FROM rules AS r
JOIN (
  SELECT id, MAX(inserted_at) AS inserted_at FROM rules GROUP BY id
) AS recent_rules
ON (
  recent_rules.id = r.id
  AND recent_rules.inserted_at = r.inserted_at)
```

I'm having trouble expessing this in Ecto. I tried something like this:

```
maxes =
  from(m in Rule,
    select: {m.id, max(m.inserted_at)},
    group_by: m.id)

from(r in Rule,
  join: m in ^maxes, on: r.id == m.id and r.inserted_at == m.inserted_at)
```

But trying to run this, I hit a restriction:

> queries in joins can only have `where` conditions in query

suggesting `maxes` must just be a `SELECT _ FROM _ WHERE` form.

If I try switching `maxes` and `Rule` in the JOIN:

```
maxes =
  from(m in Rule,
    select: {m.id, max(m.inserted_at)},
    group_by: m.id)

from(m in maxes,
  join: r in Rule, on: r.id == m.id and r.inserted_at == m.inserted_at)
```

then I'm not able to `SELECT` the whole row, just `id` and `MAX(inserted_at)`.

Does anyone know how to do this JOIN? Or a better way to query append-only in Ecto? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Doing `m in ^maxes` is not running a subquery but either query composition (if in a from) or converting the query to a join (in a join). In both cases, you are changing the same query. Given your initial query, I believe you want subqueries.

Also note that a subquery requires the `select` to return a map, so we can refer to the fields later on. Something along these lines should work:

```
maxes =
  from(m in Rule,
    select: %{id: m.id, inserted_at: max(m.inserted_at)},
    group_by: m.id)

from(r in Rule,
  join: m in ^subquery(maxes), on: r.id == m.id and r.inserted_at == m.inserted_at)
```

PS: I have pushed a commit to Ecto that clarifies the error message in cases like yours.

```
invalid query was interpolated in a join.
If you want to pass a query to a join, you must either:

  1. Make sure the query only has `where` conditions (which will be converted to ON clauses)
  2. Or wrap the query in a subquery by calling subquery(query)
```

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't known about `subquery/2`, this helps a lot!  Also, as someone writing Erlang since 2010, just want to express appreciation for Elixir—it's an absolute joy, resulting from many deliberate choices I'm grateful for.